# Clearing localStorage of a page without affecting other localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

In my code i have set multiple items in local storage, when i use localStorage.clear() it resets the variable of my other webapps as well, and i do not want to remove each item one by one, i want to reset the specific container of my localStorage of that page, whole storage of my browser.

here is my code

```
if (localStorage.container) {
    var i = parseInt(localStorage.container);
} else {
    localStorage.setItem('container', "0");
    var i = parseInt(localStorage.container);
}

var caseNum = $("#caseNum").val();
localStorage.setItem('caseNum' + i, caseNum);

var empName = checkName()
localStorage.setItem('empName' + i, empName);

var emp = $("#emp").val();
localStorage.setItem('emp' + i, emp);

var trigTime = $("#trigTime").val();
localStorage.setItem('trigTime' + i, trigTime);

var country = $("#country").val();
localStorage.setItem('country' + i, country);

var date = $("#date").val();
localStorage.setItem('date' + i, date);

var caseDate = $("#date").val();
localStorage.setItem('caseDate' + i, caseDate);

var doneTime = currTime();
localStorage.setItem('doneTime' + i, doneTime);

var dispo = $("#dispo").val();
localStorage.setItem('dispo' + i, dispo);

var subDispo = $("#subDispo").val();
localStorage.setItem('subDispo' + i, subDispo);

var caseCount = $("#caseCount").val();
localStorage.setItem('caseCount' + i, caseCount);

var A1 = '';
localStorage.setItem('A1' + i, A1);

var A2 = '';
localStorage.setItem('A2' + i, A2);

var A3 = '';
localStorage.setItem('A3' + i, A3);

var project = $("input[type='radio'][name='project']:checked").val();
localStorage.setItem('project' + i, project);

var prefix = '';
if (country == "Kenya") {
    prefix = "KY";
}
localStorage.setItem('prefix' + i, prefix);

var called1 = '';
if ($("#called0").prop("checked") == true) {
    called1 = "Yes";
} else if ($("#called0").prop("checked") == false) {
    called1 = "No";
}
localStorage.setItem('called1' + i, called1);

i++;
localStorage.setItem('container', i);
```

that code is for my dynamic table, do it is creating an array of entries in tablerow.

i tried to use localStorage.removeItem(container); but does not work. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: `localStorage.removeItem("container")` will work for you

Comment: save a JSON version of a dictionnary per web-app, and clear only this dictionnary : `localStorage.setItem('my-web-app#1', JSON.stringify({caseNum: 'XXX', trigTime: 'YYY' ...}));` At each edit, you'll parse the dictionnary, update it, and save its JSON version entirely again.

Comment: You can also name local storage variable by prepending your app name to the storage variable name... window.localStorage.setItem('myAppName.container', container);

Comment: This will prevent name collisions with other sites and applications

Comment: thanks for the ideas guys, @sravan that worked for me thanks man. thanks.